# Tkinter - Removing multiple records with checkboxes

Tags: python, tkinter, checkbox

I'm attempting to populate a list of results (in this example from a python list) and give each result it's own `Checkbutton`. That works with the `variable=Variable()` piece in the TK button code, though I'm not exactly sure how it works.
When the results are generated I need to be able to select them and then delete the selected ones. I'm looking for help to get the state of each check box so I can delete that entry. Here is the code I have so far.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("DB Sandbox")
root.geometry("400x400")

def del_selected():
    pass

results = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']

for result in results:
        l = Checkbutton(root, text=result, variable=Variable())
        l.pack()

delbutt = Button(root, text="Delete Selected", command=del_selected)
delbutt.pack(pady=10)


root.mainloop()
```

Any direction on this is much appreciated!

Comment: What is `Variable()` creating/returning?

Comment: When I started building this I found using that as a solution to loop through the list and create the output. As I stated above, i'm not really sure how that class works. When trying to research it, I couldn't find an explanation. Hoping someone here will.

Comment: `variable=Variable()` What does this really mean? Or what are you trying to do? with that?

Comment: `tkinter` supports several kinds of ["variable" classes](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm), and `intVar`s are often used with `Checkbox` widgets. Without more context, it's difficult to understand your question or what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Here's some [information](https://web.archive.org/web/20190512164523id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/checkbutton.html) on using `Checkbutton` widgets (with `IntVar`s).

Comment: @martineau and @CoolCloud `Variable` is the base class of `StringVar`, `IntVar`, etc.  Normally it should not be used directly.

Comment: Better use a `Listbox` with multiple selections enabled instead of list of `Checkbutton`.

Comment: @acw1668: Thanks, that's [semi-]useful information. `;¬)`

Answer (score 0):

As @acw1668 mentioned in the comments, `Checkbutton` is not probably the best choice for this task, but if you really want to, you need keep track of every checkbox and it's variable, like so:

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("DB Sandbox")
root.geometry("400x400")

def del_selected():
    global check_buttons, butt_vars # the best approach would be OOP, but this works
    for button, var in zip(check_buttons, butt_vars):
        if var.get(): # button selected: var.get() == 1, otherwise: var.get() == 0
            button.forget() # remove it from the geometry manager

results = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
# this holds the variables to check whether the checkbox is selected or not
butt_vars = [IntVar() for _ in range(len(results))]
# this holds the checkbutton instances
check_buttons = [Checkbutton(root, text=x, variable=butt_vars[i]) for i, x in enumerate(results)]

for butt in check_buttons:
        butt.pack()

delbutt = Button(root, text="Delete Selected", command=del_selected)
delbutt.pack(pady=10)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think OP wants to remove the selected items in `results` as well.